# how to access ng-template attribute with jquery

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-calendar

I'am using angular-calendar with a custom template as given here : https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/#/custom-templates

i have the ng-template element in my html

```
<ng-template #customCellTemplate let-day="day" let-viewDate="event"let-locale="locale" [let-status]="statuses">
```

and called the customCellTemplate in my mwl-calendar-month-view element

```
  <mwl-calendar-month-view [viewDate]="viewDate" [events]="events"   (eventClicked)="handleEvent('Clicked', $event.event)"
    [cellTemplate]="customCellTemplate">
  </mwl-calendar-month-view>
```

now i want to access day (in ng-template - let-day="day") in my component.ts file

i think i can do it with jquery but don't know how,
and if there is another way then please let me know

Thanks!!

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to mix Angular with JQuery. Almost everything that could be done JQuery could be done directly with Angular. Exactly why would you like to access the element in the component.ts file?

Comment: i want to access day attribute for this..(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64675233/bind-status-value-from-component-to-html-in-angular-calendar) purpose .

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ViewChild directive to access the element. Then you can log it to see all the info available.

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('customCellTemplate') customCellTemplate : TemplateRef;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(customCellTemplate);
  }
}
```

I think this way lets you access those parameters.

Comment: Thanks @eloyra,it consoles the whole template , but i can't find day anywhere.How to access day attr??

Comment: Maybe what you need is to abstract what you are defining as an ng-template into a component. That way those let-name variables could be just standard @Input parameters.

Comment: can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: Check [this](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-components). You basically create a .html with your standard HTML and a .ts with a special decorator that indicates you are defining a component and assign the HTML and a tag name to that component. In this .ts file you then can define all the logic you want and [access @Input parameters](https://angular.io/api/core/Input). Finally where you are now using an ng-template, you would just place your custom component tag, let's say <app-myComponent day="whatever"></app-myComponent>  (components can't self-close).